# Origin of the Bavarian "In oana dua" ("all the time")

Tags: etymology, bavarian

First of all, I'm not sure if the question is appropriate here or if it should be posted in linguistics, but since Bavarian is listed as language under the "Dachsprache", I think it's appropriate.

I tried to research it, but I didn't come up with anything that would provide me more evidence.

"In oana dua" is an interesting expression, because the word "dua" is always ever only found in this context. So the question is, where does it come from?

I have 3 leads that seem logical to me:

- from Latin "durare", compare to English "duration", which would make the sentence "in one duration"
- a noun formed from the Bavarian "i dua" ("I do"), which would mean make the sentence "in one doing"
- from "tour" (In Bavarian "T" often turns into "D", so pronounced "dua")

Perhaps there are more possible explanations, so if you have one, please add them.

**Edit:** Since I have been asked to add a translation and examples:

Translation:
ENG: all the time
GER: die ganze Zeit

Examples:
BAR: "In oana dua hód'a gmosad."
GER: "Die ganze Zeit hat er gemeckert."
ENG: "He complained all the time."

BAR: "Des géd haid šo in oana dua so."
GER: "Das geht heute schon die ganze Zeit so."
ENG: "It's been going on like this the whole day."

Comment: Es wäre interessant gewesen, wenn Du die Bedeutung erklärt und Beispiele angegeben hättest.

Comment: Du hast einen deutsch klingenden Namen und in deinem Profil steht (zwar auf englisch, aber es steht da), dass du Bayer bist. Trotzdem stellst du hier im Deutsch-Forum eine Frage auf Englisch über einen Dialektbegriff aus genau deiner Heimatregion. Das macht mich neugierig: Was ist deine Muttersprache? Warum fragst du nicht auf Deutsch?

Comment: @Medi1Saif I *think* (and it definitely sounds more natural if it’s the case), OP decided to use *š* (Czech/Slovak/Slovene/Serbian/Croatian/other minorities’ *s* with hachek) to symbolise the sound commonly written as *sch*. I would have written ‘des gäd heid scho in oana Tour so.’

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Meine Muttersprache ist Bairisch; Ich hab auf Englisch gefragt damit Leute die kein Deutsch sprechen es auch verstehen. Ich nehme mal an dass die meissten Deutschen hier Englisch können, aber evtl. nicht alle nicht-Deutschen Deutsch.

Comment: @Jan: Yes, you are right, though I don't see the comment from Medi1Saif, so I don't know what he asked.

Comment: @MatthiasSchreiber: Das hier kein englisch-Forum, sondern ein Deutsch-Forum. Das heißt: 100% aller Besucher hier sprechen Deutsch oder bemühen sich zumindest Deutsch zu verstehen. Aber weniger als 100% der Besucher dieser Seite können Englisch. Es gibt auch Araber, Italiener, Russen, Chinesen usw. die hier Fragen stellen, und ALLE interessieren sich für Deutsch, aber NICHT ALLE können Englisch.

Comment: @MatthiasSchreiber Im Prinzip hat Medi das *š* als *s* interpretiert und sich gewundert, warum da zwei *so* drin stehen ;) Nicht weiter relevant ^^

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This also exists in standard German as

> in einer Tour

see [Redensarten-Index](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~in%20einer%20Tour&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou), so it's your third choice.

Comment: Well, this gives more evidence towards it but doesn't entirely solve it. It might very well be that it has its origin in Bavarian and got "molded" into German. Something similar happened to "Christkindl" into American "Chris Kringle".

Comment: I live since 51 years in Austria (first 30 years in Graz, then 20 years in Vienna, since a few month in St. Pölten), and Austrian dialects belong to the bavarian dialect group. The phrase »in ana Tua« or »in ana Dua« is very common also in the regions where i live (there is almost no difference between »d« and »t« in bavarian dialects), and I can proof, that guidot is right. In standard German it is »in einer Tour« and means »ständig« or »immer«.

Answer (score 2):

as guidot says and you hypothesized 'dua' literally means 'tour'.
'dua' is just pronounced heavily bavarian.

so etymologically you would have to look into [french](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tour) .